# CSS: check if href is a file?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I know I can use

```
a[href$='.mov']
```

to check if the href refers to a .mov file.

However, can I generally check if the `href` attribute refers to a file? So any file with a suffix at the end?

Comment: You cannot rely on URLs alone to determine whether there is a real file somewhere on a site.

Comment: Short of giving a list of specific filetypes, I don't think this is something that CSS can reasonably address.

Comment: can you define "file"?  Every href points to a file of one kind (or another or an anchor within a file). It sounds like you have an idea of what is a "real file" ... maybe you don't want to include scripts, for instance (or directories, but even they are just files , after a fashion).  And don't be so sure that you can make judegments based on an extension... can you clarfiy what you want to do & then we can try to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell from URL, and also the definition of a *file* is subjective. Technically, `index.html` is a file, but probably not a file from the prospective of your question.

If you had a list of known file extensions you wanted to select, you could do something like this

```
a[href$='.mov'],
a[href$='.exe'] {
    color: red;
}
```

Otherwise if you had a server side language, you could follow the links and look for download response headers (look for `Content-Disposition: inline`) though this is also probably way too much overhead and a bad idea.

I don't think the *look for any link with extension* is a good idea to determine if it links to a *file*. You probably want a whitelist, and check against that.

Comment: alright, got it! i'll find a different solution. dumb question in the first place. of course html-documents are files too. sorry for the question!

Comment: @mathiregister Don't be sorry! If you learned something, I guess it was worthwhile :)